# Select values with duplicate max values sql

Tags: sql, oracle, max

I have a table made up of dates and sales totals for the particular date. I would like to be able to query the table and select the following: max sales,  the date associated with the max sale figure, sum of all sales,  and the minimum date in the table. One additional complication is that there are duplicate max values. I don't care which max value is chosen but I just want one at random. This is for Oracle.

Here is what I tried. It was using a sub query.

```
Select sales,  date,  min(date),  sum(sales)  from table
    Where sales = (select distinct(max(sales)) from table)
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: And what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Select values with duplicate max values sql you can try this to solve your problem i wish may be help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
   max(sales),
   max(date_) keep (dense_rank first order by sales desc),
   sum(sales),
   min(date_)
from
   table_
```

See also [This SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ec7b0/5)